# Is there an efficient way to obtain my friend's photos from Facebook API?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, api, request

A little background info; I'm making an iOS App that uses facebook integration.  I am using Parse (www.parse.com) as my back-end to store the facebook ids, and anything else I need for my App. On the app, I have three views which show the following:  My photos, My friends, My Public photos.  These are not ALL photos, but just the ones that correspond to the App (Similar to when you upload a photo from your phone, it uploads to the "Mobile Uploads" album).  Getting my photos and my public photos is easy since I just make a query to parse requesting the photo ids whose author is me.

Now my full question is the following.  If I were to have an Array containing all of my friend's facebook IDs, is there a way to obtain all their photos that correspond to my App WITHOUT iterating for each element in this array?  I do not wish to do this since it would mean sending N requests to the server, which is not so efficient.  Does any one know a work around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FQL to query for the photos in your app's albums (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/).  aid==album id.

You can narrow the search using and `IN` clause tied to the specific album id's you want http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/

Comment: Thanks! Your idea was the base for solving the problem, than you very much ^__^

Comment: Awesome.  Glad to be of assistance!! Happy coding.